# Matching a two lists and giving the output word in second list

Tags: arrays, r

'

```
require(readxl)
head(gene) <- read_excel("Desktop/test2/practiceversion.xlsx")
head(listofnames) <- read.delim("Documents/t2g_clean.txt")
listofnames_1 <- listofnames[,1]
listofnames_2 <- listofnames[,2]
realgenename <- listofnames[,3]
gene_name <- gene[,2]
isoform <-gene[,3]
```

'

```
 require(dplyr)
listofnames %>% 
  filter( listofnames_1 %in% gene_name | listofnames_2 %in% gene_name ) %>%
  select(listofnames) %>%
  write.tsv(., "Documents/list.txt", sep="\t", quote = FALSE)
```

I am trying to compare words from one list to words in rows of another list and output the row of the second list that the word was in. I know in python I can use the word "word" and"lst" but I can't in r. How would i solve this?

Comment: Please specify more clearly the structure of `listofnames`. Is it a `data.frame` where `lst` is the first column? Do you want to print the third column of `listofnames` that match your condition?

Comment: listofnames is a 209569 (rows) x 3 (columns) array and lst is each row in the array.

Comment: You want compare `word` against `lst` right? I'm guessing `lst` is also a list of gene names that constitute an `id` in `listofnames`. This `id` is the first column in `listofnames`? Also, do you want to print only the 3rd column or all 3 columns?

Comment: Yeah I want to compare word against lst. the ID is either in the first or second column of listofnames and I want to print the gene name which is in the third column of listofnames

Answer (score 0):

I made up a fake data.frame based on your comments:

```
gene_name <- letters[seq(1,20,3)]
listofnames <- data.frame( id1 = rep(letters[1:10],2),
                           id2 = rep(letters[11:20],2),
                           value = 1:20 )
```

I'm going to use the package `dplyr`, which you can install with `install.packages("dplyr")` and load with `library(dplyr)`. Here's the code block:

```
library(dplyr)

listofnames %>% 
filter( id1 %in% gene_name | id2 %in% gene_name ) %>%
select(value) %>%
write.tsv(., "Documents/list.txt", sep="\t", quote = FALSE)
```

This will start with `listofnames`, `filter` rows that match the condition `id1 %in% gene_name | id2 %in% gene_name`, `select` only the `value` column, and `write.tsv` the result.

Comment: When i tried your method, the error I am getting is : Error in combine_vars(vars, ind_list) : Position must be between 0 and n

Comment: Did you run my code? Or did you adapt the code with your data? If the latter, you'll need to show what `gene_name` and `listofnames` looks like...Could you update your original post with `head` of each data. Use `head(gene_name)` for instance.

Comment: require(readxl)
gene <- read_excel("Desktop/test2/practiceversion.xlsx")
listofnames <- read.delim("Documents/t2g_clean.txt")
listofnames_1 <- listofnames[,1]
listofnames_2 <- listofnames[,2]
realgenename <- listofnames[,3]
gene_name <- gene[,2]
isoform <-gene[,3]

require(dplyr)
listofnames %>% 
filter( listofnames_1 %in% gene_name | listofnames_2 %in% gene_name ) %>%
select(listofnames) %>%
write.tsv(., "Documents/list.txt", sep="\t", quote = FALSE)

Comment: Please show the output for `head(gene)` and `head(listofnames)`

Comment: Please type `head(gene)` into your R command line, and publish the output...Same for `head(listofnames)`

Comment: just added the head

Comment: Please load your data `gene <- read_excel("Desktop/test2/practiceversion.xlsx")`, then type `head(gene)` and publish the output. Please load your data `listofnames <- read.delim("Documents/t2g_clean.txt")`, then type `head(listofnames)` and publish the output.

Comment: I tried that and this is what i get: Error: `listofnames` must resolve to integer column positions, not a list

Comment: Looks like you aren't loading your data properly. Please look at the documentation for `readr::read_delim()`

Comment: I am getting an output, but the only output is: "value"

Comment: It is the column name. There is no data you are operating on.